# Help Trump build the wall!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Trump needs the wall constructed and you are going to do it! To most efficiently build his wall I have created a simple, repeatable pattern for you to use:

```
    __   __    
   |  |_|  |   
___|       |___
-   -   -   -  
 - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -
———————————————
```

Trump will tell you how many wall segments he needs and you will build them to look just like this.

Here is the pattern:

```
    __   __     <-- 4-2-3-2-4          ' _ _ '
   |  |_|  |    <-- 3-1-2-1-1-1-2-1-3  ' | |_| | '
___|       |___ <-- 3-1-7-1-3          '_| |_'
-   -   -   -   <-- 1-3-1-3-1-3-1-1    '- - - - '
 - - - - - - -  <-- 1-1-...-1-1        ' - -...- - '
- - - - - - - - <-- 1-1-...-1-1        '- - ... - -'
——————————————— <-- 15                 Unicode U+2014
```

Input will always be an integer >0.

Test cases:

```
1
    __   __    
   |  |_|  |   
___|       |___
-   -   -   -  
 - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -
———————————————

2
    __   __        __   __    
   |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |   
___|       |______|       |___
-   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  
 - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -
——————————————————————————————

5
    __   __        __   __        __   __        __   __        __   __
   |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |
___|       |______|       |______|       |______|       |______|       |___
-   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  -   -   -   -
 - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

Since you need to do this fast, write the shortest program possible!

<sub>If it helps, I wrote the challenge first, title last ;)</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 38 bytes

```
•4H’*»È%f·ù„áÅ'4•4B3ÝJ"_ -|"‡8ô€ûvy¹×»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#AUIAvf//4oCiNEjigJkqwrvDiCVmwrfDueKAnsOhw4UnNOKAojRCM8OdSiJfIC18IuKAoTjDtOKCrMO7dnnCucOXwrv//zM)

```
•4H’*»È%f·ù„áÅ'4•     # Push '1724427993555739020619095486300160'
4B                    # Convert to base 4 (turns it into an 8x8 bitmap).
  3ÝJ"_ -|"‡          # Replace digits 0-3 with _, , -, or |.
            8ô        # Split into pieces of 8.
              €û      # Palindromize each piece.
                vy¹×» # For each row, dupe it n times (hori) and print it.
```

***1724427993555739020619095486300160 converted to base-4:***

`11110011111311300003111121112111121212122121212100000000`

***11110011111311300003111121112111121212122121212100000000 with characters replaced:***

`__     |  |____|    -   -    - - - -- - - - ________`

***Previous pattern split into 8 pieces:***

```
    __  
   |  |_
___|    
-   -   
 - - - -
- - - - 
________
```

***Then you palindromize, and make it as long as needed through repetition.***

Answer (score 28):

## CJam, 52 bytes

```
F,ri*"s@;b6(MBZF,fu"128b6b"_ 
|-—"f=N/ff=zN*
```

Includes a bunch of unprintable ASCII characters. The hexdump of the first string literal pushed is:

```
01 73 06 40 3B 62 36 28 1E 4D 07 42 5A 14 1B 46 2C 66 75
```

[Try it here!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%01s%06%40%3Bb6(%1EM%07BZ%14%1BF%2Cfu%22128b6b%22_%20%0A%7C-%E2%80%94%22f%3DN%2FFf*Ff%3Crif*N*&input=5)

### Explanation

The above hexdump is interpreted as a base-128 number, then converted to base 6, to get this list:

```
[1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 2
 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 0 3 1 1 3 2
 0 0 0 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 2
 4 1 1 1 2
 1 4 2
 4 1 2
 5]
```

To this, we apply the mapping `0 → _`, `1 → space`, `2 → \n`, `3 → |`, `4 → -`, `5 → —`. This gets us the string:

```
    __   __
   |  |_|  |
___|       |
-   
 -
- 
—
```

It consists of the "period" of each line; i.e. we can cycle the fifth line `" -"` to get `" - - - - - - - "`.

Then, we execute this subprogram:

```
N/               Split into lines.
  Ff*            Repeat each line 15 times (to cycle it).
     Ff<         Take the first 15 chars of each line.
        rif*     Repeat these chars input() times.
            N*   Join lines.
```

(The new version does this in a slightly different way that I actually can't wrap my head around myself very well, because it uses `ff=`.)

Comment: What is this I don't even

Comment: Was this language especially made for this answer?

Comment: @ErdalG. No. Though [CJam](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CJam) was indeed made by a PPCG regular ([aditsu](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7416/aditsu)), it's been around for quite some time. You'll find it all over the site. :)

Comment: @AlexA. Ok make more sense now. I'm quite new here, thanks! :)

Comment: @ErdalG. My pleasure. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>116</s> 115 bytes

```js
n=>"__   __    n|  |_|  |   n|       |___n -  n- n -n—".split`n`.map(l=>l.repeat(15).slice(-15).repeat(n)).join`
`
```

*Saved a byte thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!*

### Explanation

Pretty much the same as [@Mauris' CJam method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67463/46855), but without the character mapping.

The wall parts are in the format:

```
__   __    
|  |_|  |   
|       |___
 -  
- 
 -
—
```

because if you repeat each line 15 times you get:

```
...    __   __    __   __    __   __    
... |  |_|  |   |  |_|  |   |  |_|  |   
... |       |___|       |___|       |___
 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -  
          - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
           - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                         ———————————————
```

and after slicing to just the last 15 characters you get:

```
    __   __    
   |  |_|  |   
___|       |___
-   -   -   -  
 - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -
———————————————
```

#### Ungolfed

```js
n=>
  
  // array of wall line parts
  "__   __    n|  |_|  |   n|       |___n -  n- n -n—".split`n`
  
  .map(l=>       // for each wall line
    l.repeat(15) // repeat the line 15 times to create a complete wall line
    .slice(-15)  // each wall piece is only 15 characters long
    .repeat(n)   // repeat the wall n times
  )
  .join`
`                // output the resulting wall
```

### Test

```js
var solution = n=>"__   __    n|  |_|  |   n|       |___n -  n- n -n—".split`n`.map(l=>l.repeat(15).slice(-15).repeat(n)).join`
`
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="result.textContent=solution(+this.value)" />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Can you save a byte by using `.slice(-15)` instead?

Comment: Fix is easy, just use the right minimum part instead of the left minimum part: `__   __    n|  |_|  |   n|       |___n -  n- n -n—`

Comment: Very clever, nice job!

Comment: @Neil Ah, you're right. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/), 135 bytes

<s>Considerable golfing can be done.</s> Turn off pretty print and clear the output for a better result. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=b0hwQXRvUysqIiAtIjcnIG9uKyByUyIgLSIrKysrKysrKysrKysqIiAgICBfXyAgIF9fICAgICJqSCoiICAgfCAgfF98ICB8ICAgImpIKiJfX198ICAgICAgIHxfX18iakgqaiItICAgLSAgIC0gICAtICAiSCpTakgqbmpIKk0zNWon4oCU&input=MQoKMgoKMw). Also, use [this](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=b0hwQXRvUysqIiAtIjcnIG9uKyByUyIgLSIKb2pQIllPVVIgTlVNQkVSIEhFUkUhIgorKysrKysrKysrKysqIiAgICBfXyAgIF9fICAgICJqSCoiICAgfCAgfF98ICB8ICAgImpIKiJfX198ICAgICAgIHxfX18iakgqaiItICAgLSAgIC0gICAtICAiSCpTakgqbmpIKk0zNWon4oCU) to test an arbitrary number with more ease.

```
oHpAt++++++++++++*"    __   __    "jH*"   |  |_|  |   "jH*"___|       |___"jH*j"-   -   -   -  "H*+*" -"7' jH*"- - - - - - - -"jH*M35j'—
```

I will add an explanation later.

Comment: @Connor O'Brien so what is the eta looking like on that explanation :D

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>116</s> <s>118</s> 108 bytes

```
h n=take(n*15).cycle
f n=unlines$h n.h 1<$>lines"    __   __\n   |  |_|  |\n___|       |\n-   \n -\n- \n—"
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> putStr $ f 3
    __   __        __   __        __   __    
   |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |   
___|       |______|       |______|       |___
-   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  
 - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -
—————————————————————————————————————————————
```

This uses the same strategy as other answers here: each line of the wall is one cycle of the pattern, e.g. "- " (dash + space) for the second last line. Repeat each pattern, take 15 chars to get one wall segment, repeat again and take `15*n` chars for `n` segments.

Edit: @Mauris found 10 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: The bottom line should be — (U+2014), not an ASCII dash; I think this means you lose 2 bytes.

Comment: @Mauris: you're right. Fixed it. Thanks for finding out.

Comment: You can actually terminate the periods for lines 1-3 earlier, saving 4+3+3 bytes. (My CJam answer does the same thing.)

Comment: @Mauris: ah yes, because the first cycle is cut off after 15 chars. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + Linux utilities (<s>247</s> <s>186</s> 180 bytes)

```
read x
for i in {1..7}
do
tail -n +7 $0|gzip -dc|sed -nr "$i s/(.*)/$(printf '\\1%.0s' $(seq 1 $x))/p"
done
exit
ˈ ELzVSPPPȏǑ
\@\Dk>ĄÚ ܋ɀÜ@r²uٞ5L! ͠
```

Since unprintable characters have been generously used in the construction of the above script, here's a hexdump:

```
00000000  72 65 61 64 20 78 0a 66  6f 72 20 69 20 69 6e 20  |read x.for i in |
00000010  7b 31 2e 2e 37 7d 0a 64  6f 0a 74 61 69 6c 20 2d  |{1..7}.do.tail -|
00000020  6e 20 2b 37 20 24 30 7c  67 7a 69 70 20 2d 64 63  |n +7 $0|gzip -dc|
00000030  7c 73 65 64 20 2d 6e 72  20 22 24 69 20 73 2f 28  ||sed -nr "$i s/(|
00000040  2e 2a 29 2f 24 28 70 72  69 6e 74 66 20 27 5c 5c  |.*)/$(printf '\\|
00000050  31 25 2e 30 73 27 20 24  28 73 65 71 20 31 20 24  |1%.0s' $(seq 1 $|
00000060  78 29 29 2f 70 22 0a 64  6f 6e 65 0a 65 78 69 74  |x))/p".done.exit|
00000070  0a 1f 8b 08 00 45 4c 7a  56 02 03 53 50 50 50 88  |.....ELzV..SPPP.|
00000080  8f 87 11 0a 5c 40 5c 03  44 f1 35 60 5a 81 2b 3e  |....\@\.D.5`Z.+>|
00000090  1e c4 04 83 1a 20 9b 4b  17 c8 40 c2 5c 40 02 19  |..... .K..@.\@..|
000000a0  72 a1 72 75 b9 1e 35 4c  21 1e 01 00 f3 30 f0 f9  |r.ru..5L!....0..|
000000b0  8d 00 00 00                                       |....|
000000b4
```

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell, <s>103</s> 100 characters (105 bytes on disk, 102 w/o BOM)

Pretty much the same as [@user81655 method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67467/48455).

```powershell
Param($c)'    __   __n   |  |_|  |n___|       |n-   n -n- n—'-split'n'|%{($_*15).Substring(0,15)*$c}
```

#### Ungolfed version

```powershell
# Assign input to variable,
Param($c)

# Split array of wall parts and send them down the pipeline
'    __   __n   |  |_|  |n___|       |n-   n -n- n—' -split 'n' |
    ForEach-Object { # For each piece of wall
        ($_*15) # Repeat the line 15 times to create a complete wall line
        .Substring(0,15) # Each wall piece is only 15 characters long
        *$c # Repeat the wall n times
    }
```

#### Usage example

```
PS> .\TrumpWall.ps1 3
    __   __        __   __        __   __    
   |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |   
___|       |______|       |______|       |___
-   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  
 - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - 
- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -
—————————————————————————————————————————————
```

Comment: 97 bytes: `param($c);'    __   __n   |  |_|  |n___|       |n-   n -n- n—'-split'n'|%{-join($_*15)[0..14]*$c}`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP 5.4, ( <s>182</s> 175 characters )

```
foreach(['    __   __    ','   |  |_|  |   ','___|       |___','-   -   -   -  ', ' - - - - - - - ','- - - - - - - -','———————————————'] as$d)echo str_repeat($d,$argv[1])."\n";
```

Ungolfed Version

```
$s=['    __   __    ',
    '   |  |_|  |   ',
    '___|       |___',
    '-   -   -   -  ',
    ' - - - - - - - ',
    '- - - - - - - -',
    '———————————————'
];
foreach($s as $d) {
    echo str_repeat($d,$argv[1])."\n";
}
```

[ 7 characters saved by follow Blackhole suggestion. ]

Another version with less bytes but more characters

## PHP 5.4, ( 176 characters, 178 bytes )

```
foreach(['    __   __    ','   |  |_|  |   ','___|       |___','-   -   -   -  ',' - - - - - - - ','- - - - - - - -',str_repeat('—',15)] as$d)echo str_repeat($d,$argv[1])."\n";
```

Just replace 15 instances of m-dash with one dash with str_repeat function

Comment: 1) Don't define a variable for `$s`, use it directly in your loop: `foreach([…,…] as $d)` 2) Remove the unless space before `$d`: `foreach(… as$d)` 3) Use a newline instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: You sir are not portraying the truth. Your code amounts 182 characters, but 212 bytes.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets, Sorry confused about bytes vs characters, modified

Comment: use something like https://mothereff.in/byte-counter to count the bytes

Answer (score 3):

## C, 148 bytes

```c
#define q 16843009
i;p[]={-1,q*17,q*68,q*16,-8388417,8577152,3936000};
f(n){for(i=n*105;i--;i%(15*n)||puts(""))putchar(" -|_"[p[i/15/n]>>i%15*2&3]);}
```

Score excludes the unnecessary newline before `f(n)` which is included for clarity.

the magic numbers in `p` encode the characters for the wall in base 4, which are reconstructed from the string `" -|_"` *0,1,2,3 respectively*

`16843009` in hex is `0x1010101`. this is used for the lines with `-` in them.

Because `_` is encoded by `3`, the bottom line can be encoded simply as `-1`, which is the number with all the bits set to `1`.

Comment: Nice but you can save 3 bytes by not using `#define q` and just hardcoding the values.

Comment: [136 bytes](https://tio.run/##DYyxDoMgFAB3v6IhsYKBNI8HgiE69S@MaQypLUOpse2kfjvlhstN58XD@5SCW4ax2wRwaRtEAI28umYqLptWWQtKcWHRWgWGW20MaMmxxeaOh5tpZNv8XmnoTE1j3YFmLgjhQhn3ffl9P5QQxnL457RSchL7jQzLEC5x7PtQgq7lGUfmjvSaQqRsK2YqmcvOo@JIfw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, <strike>132</strike> <strike>122</strike> 120 bytes

```
def f(n):[print((s*15*n)[:15*n])for s in['    __   __    ','   |  |_|  |   ','___|       |___','-   ', ' -', '- ', '—']]
```

Ungolfed:

```
def f(n):
    [print((s*15*n)[:15*n])for s in['    __   __    ',
                                    '   |  |_|  |   ',
                                    '___|       |___',
                                    '-   ',
                                    ' -',
                                    '- ',
                                    '—']]
```

Comment: You can remove the spaces to get `)for s in[` ...

Answer (score 2):

## PHP5.5, <s>182</s> <s>172 bytes</s> 168 bytes

based on @kuldeep.kamboj's answer, which is actually 212 bytes the moment I write this but 182 characters.
I wish the wall was a bit higher, then I could do some more optimisation ;-)

this one is 168 bytes, thanks to @JörgHülsermann

```
$r='str_repeat';$d=$r(' -',7);$x='   ';foreach(["$x __   __ $x","$x|  |_|  |$x","___|$x$x |___","-$x-$x-$x-  ","$d ","-$d",$r('—',15)] as$z){echo$r($z,$argv[1])."
";}
```

This one is 172 bytes

```
$r='str_repeat';$d=$r(' -',7);$x=$r(' ',3);foreach(["$x __   __ $x","$x|  |_|  |$x","___|$x$x |___","-$x-$x-$x-  ","$d ","-$d",$r('—',15)] as$z){echo$r($z,$argv[1])."
";}
```

This one is 182 bytes :-)

```
$r='str_repeat';$d=$r(' -',7);$x=$r(' ',4);foreach([$x.'__   __'.$x,'   |  |_|  |   ','___|       |___','-   -   -   -  ',$d.' ','-'.$d,$r('—',15)] as$z){echo $r($z,$argv[1]).'
';}
```

ungolfed version

```
$r='str_repeat';
$d=$r(' -',7);
$x=$r(' ',3);
$s=["$x __   __ $x",
    "$x|  |_|  |$x",
    "___|$x$x |___",
    "-$x-$x-$x-  ",
    "$d ",
    "-$d",
    $r('—',15)
];
foreach($s as $z) {
  echo$r($z,$argv[1])."
";
}
```

Comment: remove the space before the as and remove the brackets -3 Bytes

Comment: `$x=$r(' ',3);` can be shorten to `$x='     ';`

Comment: You do not need the brackets for the foreach loop and ` as$z` could write as `as$z`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, (161 characters, 191 bytes)

```
x=input();a=['    __   __    ','   |  |_|  |   ','___|       |___','-   -   -   -  ',' - - - - - - - ','- - - - - - - -','———————————————']
for i in a:print i*x
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 121 bytes

How I do this is by accessing each line one at a time input times, giving me stacks with the contents of each line. Then, I output a line at a time. If anyone wants me to give a more in-depth explanation, just ask (I'm currently opening presents, so...).

```
V0v7\[v1+v&V\[vDvm]a]y\[?Z]
"    __   __    "
"   |  |_|  |   "
"___|       |___"
4\["-   "]Xr
6mXr" "
8\["- "]X
"—"e\D
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=VjB2N1xbdjErdiZWXFt2RHZtXWFdeVxbP1pdCiIgICAgX18gICBfXyAgICAiCiIgICB8ICB8X3wgIHwgICAiCiJfX198ICAgICAgIHxfX18iCjRcWyItICAgIl1Ycgo2bVhyIiAiCjhcWyItICJdWAoi4oCUImVcRA&input=&args=NQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 90 keys

Assuming the input is in a buffer by itself the following will do the job (newline only for readability)

```
"aDi    __   __    ^M   |  |_|  |   ^M___|       |___^M^[
4i-   ^[xo-^[Y7P8JY2PxA ^[GVr^K-M^Vgg$d@aP
```

where `^M` is a <kbd>return</kbd>, `^[` is <kbd>escape</kbd>, `^K` is <kbd>ctrl+k</kbd> and `^V` is <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>.

This can very likely be golfed down quite a bit, as there might be much better ways of generating the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
→↔\ιδ»►℮⁰}▒║ΙOģΠp~⁵‘ ¾“ζ'¹*+'¹n*
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMTkyJXUyMTk0JTVDJXUwM0I5JXUwM0I0JUJCJXUyNUJBJXUyMTJFJXUyMDcwJTdEJXUyNTkyJXUyNTUxJXUwMzk5TyV1MDEyMyV1MDNBMHAlN0UldTIwNzUldTIwMTglMjAlQkUldTIwMUMldTAzQjYlMjclQjkqKyUyNyVCOW4q,inputs=Mg__,v=0.12)

Explanation:

```
...‘ ¾“ζ'¹*+'¹n*
...‘              push a string of the top 6 lines of 1 wall piece (no newlines)
     ¾“           push 8212
       ζ          convert to char from unicode codepoint
        '¹*       repeat 15 times
           +      add that to the previous compressed string
            '¹n   split into lines with length 15
               *  repeat horizontally input times
```

Comment: *goes back to all ascii-art questions and upvotes dzamia for beating me on literally all of them with SOGL at some point*

Answer (score 0):

## Java 11, <s>236</s> <s>235</s> <s>231</s> 229 bytes

```java
n->{String w[]={"","","","","","",""},t="- ".repeat(7);for(;n-->0;w[0]+="x __x__x ",w[1]+="x|  |_|  |x",w[2]+="___|xx |___",w[3]+="-x-x-x-  ",w[4]+=" "+t,w[5]+=t+"-")w[6]+="_".repeat(15);return"".join("\n",w).replace("x","   ");}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVHBboMwDL3vKyyfEpWgdl3XA6J/sF52pCjKKN3oaKhCKEwt384cyLRJ0zTFQc57Nsl7PqqLEsf9@5CVqq7hSRX6egdQaJubg8py2LojwLM1hX6FjBEDmkcE9rQpaqtskcEWNMQwaLG5@to2SeMrYvAr@sDGJj/nyjIUgMGaR4fKsEgLsZlHbTJPZzF2IGVHQXybLEbkBnCT7tM57N5hUspb1xEspcOWDhPduGDsfHAI4MxSvqLczlAgb5NHyr/eQK2LFY9MbhujEcNjVWiGO039PKSiknxgSJciGYE86odokn5uXkqS7h24VMUeTmQgmwxIUlDcu/dR2/wUVo0Nz0TZUjMdZmzBRyP/5Jf/8GvuB/E9Bu@9l@ZPtTWBGymoU9Vo6x816QWdt76LuTR7UyaZ6tIf6ndzDOg3/r5@@AQ)
NOTE: Java 11 isn't on TIO yet, so `String.repeat(int)` has been emulated with `repeat(String,int)` (for the same byte-count).

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                                // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  String w[]={"","","","","","",""},//  Start with seven empty rows
         t="- ".repeat(7);          //  Temp String to reduce bytes
  for(;n-->0;                       //  Loop `n` amount of times:
    w[0]+="x __x__x ",              //   Append to the first row
    w[1]+="x|  |_|  |x",            //   Append to the second row
    w[2]+="___|xx |___",            //   Append to the third row
    w[3]+="-x-x-x-  ",              //   Append to the fourth row
    w[4]+=" "+t,                    //   Append to the fifth row
    w[5]+=t+"-")                    //   Append to the sixth row
    w[6]+="_".repeat(15);           //   Append to the seventh row
  return"".join("\n",w)             //  Join all rows by new-lines
          .replace("x","   ");}     //  Then replace all "x" with three spaces,
                                    //  and return the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell + file, 92 bytes

save powershell to `get-trumpwall.ps1` (40 bytes)

```
param($c);gc f|%{-join($_*15)[0..14]*$c}
```

save data file with name `f` and data contains Unicode symbol and Linux LF only (52 bytes):

```
    __   __
   |  |_|  |
___|       |
-   
 -
- 
—
```

hex dump:

```
0000000000: 20 20 20 20 5F 5F 20 20 │ 20 5F 5F 0A 20 20 20 7C      __   __◙   |
0000000010: 20 20 7C 5F 7C 20 20 7C │ 0A 5F 5F 5F 7C 20 20 20    |_|  |◙___|
0000000020: 20 20 20 20 7C 0A 2D 20 │ 20 20 0A 20 2D 0A 2D 20      |◙-   ◙ -◙-
0000000030: 0A E2 80 94             │                          ◙—››
```

### Usage example

```
PS> .\get-trumpwall.ps1 5
    __   __        __   __        __   __        __   __        __   __
   |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |      |  |_|  |
___|       |______|       |______|       |______|       |______|       |___
-   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  -   -   -   -  -   -   -   -
 - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - -
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```